# Which part of the code shows validation errors after Post in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have one view model. It has one required `Name` property. And I have disabled client-side validation. I have this code in my action method:

```
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
```

So, everything works fine. It will highlight the required field after post. But, I can't understand that which jQuery validaion function do this process? How, jQuery Validation detects that the form has been submitted once?

I want to find that code, because I want to change it slightly. For example, I have my own helpers, which has custom validation logic. For now, my custom  helper validation are not showing after invalid Post. And, I want to add my logic to the built-in function, which I CAN NOT FIND ANYWHERE.

Comment: *"And I have disabled client-side validation."* ~ Not sure what you're asking... jQuery Validation ***IS*** "client-side" validation... and you said it has been "disabled".  Maybe that's why you can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @sparky Disabling client side validation, doesnt mean that validation messages won't be shown after submit. And I want to understand what is th function, which adds invalid styles to elements and shows validation messages. I didn't even know whether this process happens in server or client side. Could you please explain me?

Comment: Mvc has its own validation with the data annotations you set on your model. On post it simply goes to the controller then checks the modelstate errors if its valid it runs your code in the function, if not it returns the model with its errors. If you had jquery validation it would never go to the controller in the first place.

Comment: jQuery Validation is JavaScript, which only runs on the client. If you've disabled client-side validation, then jQuery Validate has nothing to do with any of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, if you have disabled client side validation, jquery validation has nothing to do with it (you have disabled it!). To briefly explain what happens when you post and return the view.

1. The `DefaultModelBinder` initializes a new instance of you model
2. The `DefaultModelBinder` then reads the form data (name/value pairs)
   and if a property name matches one of the form data values, its
   property is set (assuming its valid) and its value is also added to
   `ModelState`. If the value is not valid, the property is not set but
   its value is added to `ModelState` (the `attemptedValue`) along with
   a `ModelState` error
3. When you return the view, your `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` method
   reads the `ModelState` values and if there is an error associated
   with the property, the error message is added to the html generated
   by the `ValidationMessageFor()` method and the relevant class name
   (which highlights it) is added

You can inspect the source code for the [DefaultModelBinder](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs) and [ValidationExtensions](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/ValidationExtensions.cs) if you want to see more detail of how these work.

As for *"I want to find that code, because I want to change it slightly"*, then **DONT**. You have not indicated what you trying to do, or shown any code for your html helper extension method, but html helpers do not (and should not) contain validation logic. They are responsible for generating html based on a property and the validation attributes applied to that property.

If you have custom validation logic for a property, then you create an attribute that inherits from [ValidationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) (and if you also want client side validation then it also needs to implement [IClientValidatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable(v=vs.118).aspx)). A good guide for creating your own validation attributes is [this article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But, I will choose other answer, because he has answered firslty and correctly.

Comment: Your question was _"I want to find that code"_ Where in the accepted answer so it answer that? And _"answered correctly"_? - _"Mvc has its own validation that is **not** server side is wrong"_ - it is server side validation and _"When server side validation is enabled the validation is done before the form"_ is also wrong

Comment: @İhsanİlicali, you should be accepting the **best** answer as opposed to the first answer.  Clearly, this one is best because it *directly* answers your specific question and does not contain incorrect information.

Answer (score 2):

Mvc has its own validation that is not server side and works with the data annotations you set on your model. On post it simply goes to the controller then checks the modelstate errors if its valid it runs your code in the function, if not it returns the model with its errors. If you had jquery validation it would never go to the controller in the first place. When server side validation is enabled the validation is done before the form is sent to the controller. Without jquery it is validated at the controller. If not what you're looking for please let me know

Comment: *"When server side validation is enabled the validation is done before the form is sent to the controller."* ~  I think you meant to say *"when **CLIENT** side validation is enabled..."*